# Vaadin 7 how to get a page parameters

Tags: vaadin, vaadin7

In my Vaadin 7 application I have a following page by the following url:

```
http://example.com?wizzard#!products/68691/gps-tracker
```

How to get this page parameters(in this case - `wizzard`) from Vaadin 7 application code ?

Comment: https://vaadin.com/forum#!/thread/3226210

Comment: Thanks, but I don't see the solution there how to get page url and parameters

Comment: The request does not directly map to a UI or Page in vaadin. But you can get hold of URL (parameters) with this: https://vaadin.com/docs/-/part/framework/advanced/advanced-requesthandler.html

Comment: Thanks for this information

Comment: Please add it as answer if it helped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`String value = VaadinService.getCurrent().getCurrentRequest().getParameter("wizzard");
// wizzard present if value is not null`